# Elegant way to deal with redundant words on python class/method naming

Tags: python, django

Simple question but I'm struggling with it.

I want to create a custom object manager to a Django model just like this:

```
class Clearance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='usuário')
    level = models.CharField(choices=PERMISSION_LEVELS, max_length=20, verbose_name='nível')
    tech_support = TechSupportManager()
    user_manager = UserManagerManager()
```

OK, the problem is the redundant Manager word. I don't feel like removing the last word and just leave "UserManager" without really saying what that class suppose to do but duplicate the word feels like the wrong thing to do too.

Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Why did you decide to call it that in the first place? I'm not sure if this question fits on StackOverflow, since it seems to be a matter of subjective opinion. Django doesn't care what you call your classes, but it's a useful convention to only use `FooManager` for subclasses of models.Manager.

Comment: just rename user_manger to 'user' and the subclass to 'UserManager'

Comment: @HåkenLid my question is based on the fact that python has a very broad recommendation hints about how the code suposed to be. Is more like that. I mean, I know the name of the class ending with Manager is not mandatory but it's a convention.  My question is all about that, class naming convetion on Python

Answer (score 2):

By default, Django adds a Manager with the name objects to every Django model class. However, if you want to use objects as a field name, or if you want to use a name other than objects for the Manager, you can rename it on a per-model basis. To rename the Manager for a given class, define a class attribute of type models.Manager() on that model. For example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    #...
    people = models.Manager()
```

Using this example model, Person.objects will generate an AttributeError exception, but Person.people.all() will provide a list of all Person objects.

[You can find further information on managers, and the best practices using them at this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Manager`s can be called whatever you want.  In your specific case,  you could use a `managers.py` file (rather than having them in `models.py`) - it becomes quite obvious (and a little less redundant) to do it something like this:

```
from managers import UserManager, TechSupportManager
class Clearance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='usuário')
    level = models.CharField(choices=PERMISSION_LEVELS, max_length=20, verbose_name='nível')
    tech_support = TechSupportManager()
    user_manager = UserManagerManager()
```

and your managers file obviously has:

```
from django.db import models

class TechSupportManager(models.Manager): 
    # your manager methods here
    pass 


class UserManager(models.Manager): 
    # your manager methods here  
    pass
```

I'd point out that this would be called in the form of:

```
import Clearance

techsupport_results = Clearance.tech_support.all() 
#or whatever methods you define there.
```

...that's not the nicest call (compare with `Clearance.objects.all()` - it's clear and obvious what that does - the techsupport and user_manager methods are less clear, which is partly at the root of your question, imo.

Comment: my concern is more about the redundancy on the class name than in the attribute. I mean, even if I rename the attribute to anything else, the Manager class name, by convention, still will be ending with the word Manager. So, if I wanted a django manager to deal with users with are managers on my project, by convention my django manager class will be ManagerManager. I know it's silly, but I just wanna know what to do in that case. Name my class Manager_Manager or ManagerObjectManager. That's my question.